# How to print the words using the abstract class?

Tags: java

The result I want is...

Baby : crawl

Baby : babble

Dog : bark

Dog : walk on all fours

But the result of the above code is...

crawl

babble

bark

walk on all fours

I think "Baby : ", "Dog : " are using the abstract class too, but I don't know what code inside above code.

How can I fix this code?

Comment: If you want the output to contain "Baby : ", you better write that somewhere in your program.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Need to modify your `run()` and `sound()` methods in following way for both Baby and Dog classes:

```
run() {
  System.out.println(super.getType() + " : " + "walk on all fours");
}

sound() {
  System.out.println(super.getType() + " : " + "bark");
}
```

Comment: thx, but result is "null : walk on all fours.", "null : bark"

Comment: @ORing Remove the `private string type` in dog and baby since you already have it inherited from animal too. You are writing to the base class variable but reading from the then empty subclass.

Comment: @ORing and make the `type` field in the base class `protected`. Alternatively, use `getType()` instead of `type` in the print statements.

Comment: @ORing sorry for the previous reply. I have updated the answer now. It should work if you call `super.getType()` instead of `this.getType()`

Also I would like to explain the issue that caused `this.getType()` to fail. While initializing the Baby and Dog objects, the constructor `public Baby()` called the super class `Animal` 's constructor and the type variable remained uninitialized for Baby/Dog. So the alternative would be to use the `type` variable from the super class instead of the subclass Baby/Dog.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add '**type**' in your all print statement

For example:

> System.out.println(super.getType()+": crawl");

You cannot use `this.type` in the above statement because you have not assigned `type` to the child class variable but to the superclass variable in constructors of both child classes.

Comment: thx, but result is "null : crawl."

Comment: Ok, I got your problem! Use 'super.getType()' instead of using only 'type' in print statement.

Comment: omg! thx a lot!